# How do I properly resolve the IP of another container in a Docker Swarm? (DNS)

Tags: networking, dns, docker, docker-swarm

I'm playing with deploying services in a Docker Swarm. I'm having trouble letting a container consistently connect to a container on a different node.

Let's say I'm building a GlusterFS pool; I need to open a terminal in each container and add the gluster daemon to the pool. How do I refer to other containers in the pool? Currently I'm using an IP address, but what if a container dies and is recreated? As far as I know there's no guarantee that the new container will have the same IP address. I could use the embedded DNS server to refer to the other containers, but I can only seem to resolve container names and container IDs to IP addresses, and both of those will change if a container dies and is recreated, so there's no point.

Shouldn't I be able to resolve the *hostnames* of the other containers to their IP addresses? I assumed it would, but it doesn't.

Are there any solutions to my conundrum? (I get the sense that I might be going about using services all wrong, and that in this case I should manually create a container on each node.)

Comment: Are you trying to resolve hostnames for a situation like `container A of service X + container B of service Y` or for `container A of service X + container B of service X`? So are you talking about replicas which should be able to connect to each other using their hostnames or is your question about two different services which have to connect to each other? Later should easily be achievable by using the `--name` option of docker service create

Answer (score 10):

Depending on your exact situation, you have to use different solutions:

**Intra-service hostname resolution**

Problem: You have multiple containers (/replicas) of the same service `serviceX`, e.g.:

- container `a1b3d130275a` with hostname `serviceX.1.nq4rjbae`
- container `65040b1cada6` with hostname `serviceX.2.m9wl1f1r`
- container `944704427b9e` with hostname `serviceX.3.3d08baql`

Now, you want to retrieve the hostname of the second (`serviceX.2.m9wl1f1r`) and the third (`serviceX.3.3d08baql`) container from within container one ( `serviceX.1.nq4rjbae`).

Docker provides a solution called [container discovery](https://docs.docker.com/network/overlay/#container-discovery) using a DNS query against `tasks.$serviceName`, e.g.:

```
nslookup tasks.serviceX
[...]
Name:      tasks.serviceX
Address 1: 10.0.0.205 a1b3d130275a  (<- resolved locally by /etc/hosts)
Address 2: 10.0.0.206 serviceX.2.m9wl1f1r
Address 3: 10.0.0.207 serviceX.3.3d08baql
```

There are also discussions on making `serviceX.{1,2,3}` resolvable and therefore creating predictable hostnames.¹ ² ³ ⁴ But by now, none of these is implemented, so this solution only works at runtime.

Note: Setting the hostname using the template feature (like `docker service create ... --hostname {{.Service.Name}}.{{.Task.Slot}}`) would make the hostnames locally predicatable, but they won't be resolvable by other containers.

**Inter-service hostname resolution**

Problem: You have mutliple containers of the different services `serviceX`, `serviceY`. But only one container per service, e.g.:

- container `a1b3d130275a` with hostname `serviceX.1.nq4rjbae`
- container `65040b1cada6` with hostname `serviceY.2.m9wl1f1r`

And you want to connect to a container of another service (`serviceX`) from one service (`serviceY`) and vice versa. You only have to use the `--name` parameter:

```
docker service create --name=serviceX serviceX
docker service create --name=serviceY serviceY
```

And you can rely that container `a1b3d130275a` will be resolvable by hostname `serviceX` and container `65040b1cada6` by hostname `serviceY`.

Reference:

- [¹ Docker - Issue - Cannot access containers by hostname with Docker overlay driver in Swarm Mode](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/25236)
- [² make task-name as an net-alias to the backing container](https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/24973)
- [³ Define schema for mapping service resources into DNS](https://github.com/docker/swarmkit/issues/1242)
- [⁴ Make service network alias support templating](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/33408)